# NS_Error_Failure on Javascript POST

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with some javascript. The code snippet below creates a simple post request however it always throws an `NS_Error_failure` exception (details at the bottom of the page). Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code?

```
window.onload = function () {

    alert('0');
    try {
        var url = "Some URL";
        var request = CreateHttpRequest();
        if (request) {
            alert('1');
            request.open("POST", url, false);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            alert('2');
            request.send('');
            alert('3');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

```
    [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"
     nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  
     location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Users/Ben/Desktop/test.html :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 44"  data: no]
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686377/0x80004005-ns-error-failure-nsidomhtmlformelement-submit) may help

Comment: seen something similar with Prototype.js overriding the setRequestHeader function.

Comment: @Ben Cameron: I think this problem is down to illegal cross site requests. Did you solve your problem with UmeshA's solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error can be seen if there are,

1. URL not found
2. There is error in your server code or called URL.

There is not any visible problem in code you shared.
Please refer this [link](http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/0x80004005_%28NS_ERROR_FAILURE%29_and_other_firefox_errors)

Comment: my URL is working fine i have this error in firefox only. can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: @bhautikmewada191 Firefox threw this error when my app attempted to use `history.pushState()` with an unacceptable URL.

Answer (score 8):

I found the same problem and when I was sending all to an iframe, the problem solved when I add the "name" to the tag, maybe the target is not accesible by your script

```
<iframe id="iframe_execute" name="iframe_execute" frameborder="1" height="400" width="400"></iframe>
```