# How to get csv from url and transform it in array

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, url, csv

I'd like to get a csv file from a url and transform it into an array.
So here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Temperatures</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['annotatedtimeline']});
    var csv_as_array = [];
    function drawVisualization() {


    $.ajax({
    url: "data.txt",
    aync: false,
    success: function (csvd) {
        csv_as_array = $.csv2Array(csvd);
    }, 
    dataType: "text",
    complete: function () {
        // use the array of arrays (variable csv_as_array)
       // for further processing
    }
  });


    [Google chart code]

    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my `data.txt` is in the same folder as my `.html` file.

I know the block `success: function (csvd) { }` is not executed, because when I write `alert("toto");`, nothing happens.

Also, in the block `complete: function () { }`, I have written `alert(csv_as_array.length);` and it always shows `0`.

The error is maybe just an import of a library missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If `success` callback function was not called, it means error happened and `error` callback function would be called, if there would be one. You can try:

1. Adding `error` function, for example, a line like this `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, httpError) { alert('Error: '+textStatus); alert(httpError); },` to check for error.
2. Using absolute address in `url`

And you have a typo in the line `aync: false` - `async`, not `aync`.

Comment: Thank you, I've tested what you told me, and now, it works.
But I can only put a local url (127.0.0.1/xxx.txt), I can't put an external url.
Is it possible to use an external url ?
So here is my code : http://pastebin.com/3hZbTp0E

Comment: edit : i get a NS_ERROR_FAILURE in firefox's console after the main page gets the data.txt :

'[18:10:06,557] GET http://xxx.com/data.txt [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 86ms]
[18:10:06,558] GET http://xxx.com/data.txt [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 86ms]
--
[18:10:12,418] NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure @ http://127.0.0.1/jqmin.js:6'

Comment: @tuxben This answer describes your error case perfectly - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11202198/2619810