# Ajax 'Get' request error NS_ERROR_FAILURE: failure

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following GET request written to call a php file found on a remote server,
the code is as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://xxxxxxxxx/get_determined_prize.php", false);
xhr.send('');
console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

yet in the firefox console it shows NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure

the php file on the server side just contains the following:

```
<?php

echo "5";
?>
```

is it something wrong with my code? or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it in the same origin? Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686377/0x80004005-ns-error-failure-nsidomhtmlformelement-submit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202153/ns-error-failure-on-javascript-post

Comment: no the php file is found on a remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hit by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy): you cannot make requests to another server using `XMLHttpRequest`s.

As a work around, you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: is there a simple solution to the problem?

Comment: @AdrianDeBarro See my edit. But why don't you use the same server for this?